# How to pass an instance of a class to an array that is a parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, instance

well I have this method of which one parameter is an array:

```
public ItemToolPickaxe(int itemNum, String itemName, String iconName, Block[] usedOn, int durability, int quality) {
        super(itemNum, itemName, iconName, usedOn, durability, quality);

    }
```

Block being which block(s) it can be used on. In my code I have:

```
public static Item ironPickaxe = new ItemToolPickaxe(0, "Iron Pickaxe", "item_ironPickaxe", new Block[] { Block.stone }, 500, 75);
```

I would like the pickaxe to be used on Block.stone and any block that is an instance of `BlockOre`. `BlockOre` extends Block as seen here in my block class:

```
public static Block oreIron = new BlockOre(/*Non-Related*/);
```

So I was thinking:

```
public static Item ironPickaxe = new ItemToolPickaxe(0, "Iron Pickaxe", "item_ironShovel", new Block[] { Block.stone, BlockOre.class }, 500, 75);
```

But as you probably know by now doesn't work. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty ArrayList. Iterate through your array of Blocks, and for each item check if it is instance of BlockOre. If it is, add it to the ArrayList. When done, transform the ArayList into an array, and pass that to the Pickaxe constructor.

Edit:

Here is the code as requested:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    static class Block {};

    static class OreBlock extends Block {};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Block[] arrayOfBlocks = new Block[] {new Block(), new OreBlock(), new Block(), new OreBlock()};
        ArrayList<OreBlock> arrayListOfOreBlocks = new ArrayList<OreBlock>();
        for(Block block : arrayOfBlocks){
            if(block != null && block instanceof OreBlock){
                arrayListOfOreBlocks.add((OreBlock)block);
            }
        }
        OreBlock[] arrayOfOreBlocks = arrayListOfOreBlocks.toArray(new OreBlock[arrayListOfOreBlocks.size()]);
        System.out.println(arrayOfOreBlocks.length);
    }

}
```

It prints 2 when I run it, as expected.

Comment: is it too much to ask for an example of this, never used arrays until now nevermind arraylist

Comment: here you are, I added it.